# Argument list too long error for Find command

Tags: shell, unix

I wanted to find the file name with posted time from sub directories,
The below code was working fine but all of a sudden I'm getting Argument list too long error.

```
find /bishare/IRP_PROJECT/SXM_SFTP/*/INBOUND/* -name "*.xml" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat -c "%y  %n"   >> /appinfprd/bi/infogix/IA83/InfogixClient/Scripts/IRP/File_Posted_$CURRENT_DATE.txt
```

Comment: Could you use `find`’s `-exec` instead of `xargs`, e.g. `find … -exec stat -c "%y  %n" {} \; >> …`?

Comment: Still its giving the same error.

Comment: What is giving the error, `find`, `xargs` or the shell?

Comment: Could something like `find /bishare/IRP_PROJECT/SXM_SFTP/ -path '*/INBOUND/*.xml' …` help?

Comment: Not with my first suggestion, surely, since it doesn’t use `xargs`?

Comment: What about adding `-n 1` to `xargs`?

Comment: Working .. Thanks You....    find /bishare/IRP_PROJECT/SXM_SFTP/ -path '*/INBOUND/*.xml' -exec stat -c "%y %n" {} \; >>/appinfprd/bi/infogix/IA83/InfogixClient/Scripts/IRP/File_Posted_$CURRENT_DATE.txt

Comment: @Biffen — better to use `+` in place of `\;` as it achieves the `xargs`-style "group as many arguments into a single argument as will fit", drastically reducing the number of times `stat` is invoked.

Answer (score 2):

The error happens if the expansion of the wildcard produces more characters than will fit into `ARG_MAX`.

Try to split it up so there is no wildcard.

```
find /bishare/IRP_PROJECT/SXM_SFTP/ -type -d -name INBOUND -execdir \
    find . -name "*.xml" -type f -print0 \; |
xargs -0 stat -c "%y  %n"  >> /appinfprd/bi/infogix/IA83/InfogixClient/Scripts/IRP/File_Posted_$CURRENT_DATE.txt
```

Comment: I have tried splitting the code , Getting the below error,  Arguments to -type should contain only one letter
stat: cannot stat ';': No such file or directory

Comment: Sorry, the `\;`was in the wrong place - fixed now. The `-type` error sounds like you transcribed this incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /bishare/IRP_PROJECT/SXM_SFTP/ -path '*/INBOUND/*.xml' -exec stat -c "%y %n" {} \; >>/appinfprd/bi/infogix/IA83/InfogixClient/Scripts/IRP/File_Posted_$CURRENT_DATE.txt
```

Comment: This uses a GNU `find` feature — the `-path` option (which is not a problem as long as you know that's what you're doing and don't expect the code to work on platforms without GNU `find`).  It should use `+` in place of `\;` to achieve the effect of `xargs` creating suitably long command lines without being over-long.  Using `\;` means `stat` is executed once per matching file; using `+` means that `stat` is executed far less often.

Comment: If this works for you, good; but this is somewhat more specific than what could be deduced from the information in your question. In the future you might want to make sure you describe the expected format and amount of data in your questions.